# Use a loop to generate a two-column list in a specific order

Tags: loops, html, layout, coldfusion

I need to display a checklist on my page in a certain way. The checklist is contained within an array, which I'm currently looping through in the following manner:

```
<div class="width-100"> <!---- this is the main container --->
    <cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(steps)#" index="alpha">  
        <cfif (alpha MOD 2) EQ 1>               
            <div class="width-100">  <!--- this is the start of a 'row' --->
        </cfif>
        <div class="width-50">  <!--- this is a 'step' --->
            #steps[alpha].StepNum.xmltext#  
            <input class="f-right" type="checkbox" />
        </div>
        <cfif (alpha MOD 2) EQ 0>
            </div>  <!--- end of a 'row' --->
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
</div>
```

The above code gets me a checklist like this, where the steps alternate between 'columns':
[image: incorrect checklist]

When what I need is a checklist like this, where the first half of the steps are in the first column, and the second half are in the second column:
[image: correct checklist]

I need to keep the div structure as laid out above, where one 100% div contains 2 50% divs w/ checklist steps. I'm guessing there's an intelligent way to do this (probably with more MODs?), but I can't see it.

Comment: You must have used the wrong search terms, because this is a pretty [common task](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=coldfusion%20display%20query%20columns%20vertically&kl=us-en) ;-)

Comment: @Leigh - yes, I was more focused on the loop aspect, rather than the query, since my query returns a great deal more data than I'm displaying in this area. Aside from Ben's post, which seems more complicated than I need, none of the top results are terribly helpful.

Comment: @shimmoni - It not really that complex. It is essentially the exact same logic as in the example below. A) Determine the midpoint ie `5`. B) Then display the data. For the left column start at row `1`, for the right column start at `1 + midpoint`.

Comment: Yep, I can see the logic, but Ben's example uses 2 loops and if statements to check when to end a row (rather like I was in my original code) vs the answer below which is one loop and no if statements for closing tags. Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: Yeah, I was focusing on the logic. Not sure why he chose a double loop there either, but .. the basic counter logic is what matters `left[1,2,3...] right[1+offset,2+offset,3+offset,..]`. Once you understand that part, you can adapt it however you want :) Anyway, glad you got it worked out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it vertically instead of horizontally, just build your rows differently. First figure out how many rows you're working with:

```
<cfset numrows = Ceiling(ArrayLen(steps)/2) >
```

So for 10 records you would get 5 rows. The Ceiling call just rounds up if it's odd.

```
<div class="width-100"> <!---- this is the main container --->
    <cfloop from="1" to="#numrows#" index="alpha">  

        <div class="width-100">  <!--- this is the start of a 'row' --->

        <div class="width-50">  <!--- this is a 'step' --->
            #steps[alpha].StepNum.xmltext#  
            <input class="f-right" type="checkbox" />
        </div>
        <div class="width-50">  <!--- this is a 'step' --->
        <cfif isDefined("steps[alpha+numrows].StepNum.xmltext")>
            #steps[alpha+numrows].StepNum.xmltext#  
            <!--- next to step 1 you get step 6 --->
            <input class="f-right" type="checkbox" />
        </cfif> <!--- cfif because last one won't be defined if odd --->
        </div>

        </div>  <!--- end of a 'row' --->

    </cfloop>
</div>
```

Comment: I think I see where you're going, but I'm getting a CF error on the isDefined check: "Parameter 1 of function IsDefined, which is now steps[alpha+numrows].SortOrder.xmltext, must be a syntactically valid variable name." I tried doing the add an assigning it to a variable before using it in the isDefined, but that didnt work either.

Comment: (Edit) Yeah, you cannot use `IsDefined` with associative array notation. If `steps` is an array, just check the array length instead. Make sure it does not exceed the counter number.

Comment: Ugh.. that should be "make sure the *counter* does not exceed the array length."

Comment: Thanks. In our case the list of steps is strictly limited to 10, but it's a good idea to have the check, just in case.